# Replace value with value of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search for all cells in a column that are 0000000000, to replace the cell with the value of the cell to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
For each cell in Range(<your range>)

    If cell.value = '0000000000' then

      cell.value = cells(cell.row,cell.column-1).value

    end if

Next
```